# How do you do base conversions with a base between $0$ and $1$?

Tags: fermi-problems

Since written numbers are generally representations of powers of a base (i.e. the first slot is $b^0$, second is $b^1$, etc. with an integer between $0$ and the base in the slots), I'm having trouble understanding how to do a base conversion with a decimal (so you don't have to count, the base here is around $9 \times 10^{-17}$). The question here is asking for a Fermi answer, meaning the answer is approximately $10^x$ where $x$ is an integer. My gut tells me to use logarithms, but I'm not sure how...Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

[image]